# Canceling nanosleep() from another thread

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I'm trying code multi threaded worker and job giver program
Job giver thread pushes jobs to array with random delayed data it can be processed 1 second later or 10000... second later all depends to job giver.
Worker thread `nanosleep()`s till get shortest delayed job, then process it and remove it from job array.
All works fine except if job giver pushes shorter delayed job to array and worker thread still `nanosleep()`s to old shortest job, so its get delayed more than expected.

For now as quick fix I made signal handler with `signal()` that handling `SIGUSR1` signal.
When job giver pushes new shortest it sends `SIGUSR1` to whole program and cancels worker's `nanosleep()`.
But I don't think it's best way to do it since it sends to whole program and I just want to cancel one thread's `nanosleep()`.

So in summary how I can cancel other thread's `nanosleep()` from main thread without touching signals?

Note; I'm using pthread on linux with C language.

Note; Delays are in nanoseconds. With current setup I'm able to hit 50µs loss.

Comment: Sounds like a use case for condition variables and pthread_cond_timedwait

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say we have two mutexes one is called `x` other one is `y`

`x` is used for general locking like don't try access in same time with multiple threads. `pthread_mutex_lock` and `pthread_mutex_unlock`

`y` is used for `nanosleep`. `pthread_cond_wait`, `pthread_cond_timedwait` and `pthread_cond_signal`

For suspend I use `cond_wait` `y` then resume with `cond_signal` `y`. If I need suspend for some time like `nanosleep` I use `cond_timedwait` `y` and resume it with same way `cond_signal` `y`.

Source:
stackoverflow.com/questions/59286893/canceling-nanosleep-from-another-thread#comment104779089_59286893

Answer (score 1):

You can possibly use `pthread_kill()` to deliver the `SIGUSR1` to a single thread

From the manpage:

> The pthread_kill() function sends the signal sig to thread, a thread in the same process as the caller.  The signal is asynchronously directed to thread.
>
> If sig is 0, then no signal is sent, but error checking is still performed.

This should only have an effect to the single thread you target.

Comment: When our process gets signal from outside of our process isn't `singal()` function still registers it to signal handler function? Like when you send signal with `htop` or `top` program

Comment: @dvjawgvdhawgvbda I still am not sure if I understand what you mean. You wrote, that the signal is sent from another thread; this is, where `pthread_kill()` comes into play.

Comment: Yes but we are still able to trigger it from outside and isn't it problem? can't other programs send `SIGUSR1` to our program?

Comment: @dvjawgvdhawgvbda Yes, of course. Or a SIGINT, SIGTERM or SIGKILL. Why is this an issue?

Comment: If we get false triggers can't we process jobs wrong delayed? like early than expected

Comment: @dvjawgvdhawgvbda Well, if someone is able to inadvertedly or even maliciously send signals to a critical process, this is always a problem. You can limit the possibilities for that by using another user id for your process; then only root or the same userid may send signals to that process. Note, however, that this is not specific to your problem here.

Answer (score 1):

You have a big XY problem here. Sleeping and signals are not the way to implement coordination between threads. I'd go so far as to say that sleeping in a multithreaded program is almost always indicative of some sort of bug.

The tool for what you are trying to do is *Condition Variables*. If you're not familiar with them, I'd highly recommend [the Condition Variables part](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#ConditionVariables) of [this tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/). Instead of sleeping, your workers should be doing a *timed wait* on the condition variable, called in a loop, and exiting from the loop when the condition they're waiting for is true.